# R loop to change class for many columns in many data frames

Tags: r, class, loops

I have a list of tables

```
tablas<-list(ratingsRyUyM1, dfLikedSum,dfNotLikedSum,dfLikedQ, dfNotLikedQ)
```

And I want to convert 2 columns that I'm going to use in a join to characters. So I wrote:

```
for (i in tablas){
   for (j in c('movieId', 'userId')){
     i[, j]<-as.character(i[, j])}}
```

I run that and still get the columns as factors.

I also tried it with a function:

```
foo<-function(x){for (j in c('movieId', 'userId')){
        x[, j]<-as.character(x[, j])}
        return(x)}
```

And then:

```
lapply(tablas, foo)
```

I get:

```
> lapply(tablas, foo)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a combination of lapply and the dplyr function mutate. Define a function that does your task using mutate and as.character(), then use lapply. You also know that some joins will coerce factors to characters for you.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example if you are still stuck.

Comment: `function(x) {for (j in c('movieId', 'userId')) x[, j] <- as.character(x[, j]); x}` might work, ie, you need to return `x` in `foo`

Comment: [`purrr`](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/) is good for this sort of thing; `dmap_at` here, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if the two columns are the same in each dataframe/table, as you noted. In the future, please provide a reproducible example.

```
#install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

lst = list(df1, df2, df3, etc.)

func = function(x) {
    x = mutate(x, col1_name = as.character(col1_name))
    x = mutate(x, col2_name = as.character(col2_name))
}

output = lapply(lst, func)
```